# on longclick, contextmenu

Tags: android

i am having a simple cursor adapter list of (say)five items.  Each item in the list contains two text views. i have also implemented contextmenu in the list on long-click action.
what do i need is that, i want to get the textview values **from the list to the context-menu** for further proceedings....
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, and you are using `ListActivity`, you only need to override the `onCreateContextMenu` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "First menu item");
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Details on " + ((TextView)info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.textview_1)).getText());
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "More about " + ((TextView)info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.textview_2)).getText());
}
```

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for

Comment: you should consider accepting the answer as it will raise rekaszeru's reputation.